# how to hide images in a specific list and make them visible in a other list

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a question: is it possible to hide some images and make the same visible in another list? Here is the code:

```
<section>
    <ul class="portfolio_filters">
        <li><a href="#" data-filter="*">show all</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".new">New Logos</a></li>            
        <!--lightbox2-->
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".black ">Black & White</a></li>    
        <!--lightbox3-->
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".industrial">Industrial</a></li>    
        <!--lightbox3-->
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".mix">Mix</a></li>          
        <!--lightbox4-->
    </ul>
</section>
```

i want some images not to show in the "SHOW ALL" list, but if I click (for example) on the black and white list the same image needs to be visible.

thanks for the answers here is for example a linked image

`<div class="new col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                              <div class="portfolio_item"> <a href="images/portfolio/stimson.jpg" class="lightbox"> <img src="images/portfolio/stimson.jpg" alt="Wedding photograph">
                                   <div class="overlay">
                                        <div class="desc">
                                             <h4>Stimson</h4>
                                             <span class="cross"></span> </div>
                                   </div>
                                   </a> </div>
                                    </div>`

how to make this visible only in the " NEW LOGOS " list and not in the "SHOW All" list?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle what have you tried

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$("img").hide();

$("li a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("img").hide();
    filter = $(this).data("filter");
    if(filter=="*")
        $("img:not(.black)").show();
    else
        $(filter).show();
});
```

[Demo JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lparcerisa/86oujedp/1/)

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda hard with not all of the code. I assume that all the lists are build the same, and have the same HTML structure.

Most simple is to add a class to the specific list in which you want to hide the 'Show all', lets call that class `dontShowAll`. In your CSS you can then use:

```
.portfolio_filters.dontShowAll li:first-child { /*note that the classes a written without a space!! */
    display: none;
}
```

If you aren't able to change the HTML structure you can use child selectors:

```
section:first-child ul li:first-child { /* only from the first list */
section:nth-child(odd) ul li:first-child { /* from all the odd lists */
section:nth-child(3n) ul li:first-child { /* every third */
section:nth-child(4) ul li:first-child { /* only the fourth */
section:nth-child(n + 5) ul li:first-child { /* the fifth and all that follow */
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class like `.hidefromall` to the images you want to hide, and use a `:not()` selector:

```
<li><a href="#" data-filter=":not(.hidefromall)">show all</a></li>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to [accept your favorite answers to your questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/171394) to encourage others to help you in the future.